# How to gracefully shutdown pods when background service is running in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have a .Net application hosted in Azure Kubernetes cluster.
One is Web application - `TestWeb`. Another one is console library running as background service - `TestWorker`.
`TestWeb` receives the request from user and pushes the message to Storage Queue `st1`, whereas `TestWorker` reads the message from `st1` and processes it.
Suppose the deployment is created in cluster `AKS1` for both service.
Now I want to create new cluster `AKS2` and deploy the services `TestWeb` and `TestWorker` writing to and reading from same queue `st1`.
I can update the traffic manager endpoint to `AKS2` after deployment in AKS2 succeeds. In this way, all the request will route to `TestWeb` hosted in `AKS2`. However, `TestWorker` in AKS1 and AKS2 will still be reading from same queue.
How can I gracefully shutdown pods in AKS1 so that TestWorker deployed in AKS2 only reads from storage queue st1?
I can set replica count to 0 for all pods in AKS1 but this will not ensure that messages picked up from the queue by TestWorker in AKS1 is completely processed. If I set `grace period` to more than 30s , It may be possible that message is read at last nth second and pod shutdowns abruptly. What is the best way to gracefully shut down the pod in this case?

Comment: Your service should perform cleanup when it receives a TERM signal. K8s sends this signal before starting the grace period.